# ASP.net Repeater How to change header template caption server side?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to change the text "Employer Info" to something else depending o the state of certain variables. How do I get a reference to the caption so I can change its text?

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEmployers" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="rotoTable1">
      <caption class="rotoTableCaption1">Employer Info</caption>
  </HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ItemDataBound of the Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEmployers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptEmployers_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="rotoTable1">
            <caption class="rotoTableCaption1">
                <asp:Literal ID="EmployerCaptionLabel" runat="server" Text="Employer Info"></asp:Literal>
            </caption>
    </HeaderTemplate>
```

The in the code behind, set the caption to whatever you need:

```
protected void rptEmployers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        var employerCaption = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("EmployerCaptionLabel");
        employerCaption.Text = "<your caption here>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this using the `ItemDataBound` event on the repeater, and updating your caption with `runat=server` so you can manipulate it from the code-behind.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEmployers" OnItemDataBound="rptEmployers_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="rotoTable1">
      <caption id="CaptionCtrl" runat="server" class="rotoTableCaption1">Employer Info</caption>
  </HeaderTemplate>
```

In your code behind file, you would have something like this:

```
protected void rptEmployers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Item.ItemType)
    {
        case ListItemType.Header:

            HtmlGenericControl CaptionCtrl= (HtmlGenericControl) e.Item.FindControl("CaptionCtrl");
            CaptionCtrl.InnerHtml = "Your new text"

            break;
    }
}
```